# Stop all emails that contain multiple dots after the @ sign

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I look through my junk folder in `Outlook`, `Yahoo`, and `Gmail`, I saw a lot of spam emails. I bet most of you guys probably face these issues too.

```
Ex. wlda44246@mdf9j5dv91qkqi.w352f-a925.kevffsrw.ml
```

Those emails contain multiple dots after the @ sign. I know for sure that those are junks, why does Mail Server still let those come in ?

All of them seem to are useless emails from hackers/spammers.

Is there a way to block all emails that contain multiple dots after the @ sign?

How would one block those types of emails?

Comment: There are really only 3 dots in your email example. Each dot separates a domain level. In your case, there are 4 domain levels. Typical emails has 2 to 4 domain levels. e.g. xyz@gmail.com, no-reply@notifications.example.com, reply@rs.email.nextdoor.com, etc. So blocking email purely base on dots is a bad idea. Your mail server let spam emails in, but it is at least smart enough to put them in junk folder, right?

Comment: I guess, there will be no clean way of preventing this. :(

Comment: *"How would one block those types of emails?"* - Depending on the service provider, you may wish to try other criteria for filtering mail. For instance, in your example, blocking `.ml` domains might be an option. It seems doubtful legitimate mail is going to come from that TLD under most circumstances.